# Running a PHP file using AJAX and sending parameters

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to edit a file on my server when a user clicks a button on my web page. I generate a table of buttons using php. STRING1, STRING2 and BOOL are variables I pass to my function. The editPlist() function I made is called and the test alert() shows. The problem is that the php file is to run. I am not getting any errors either. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

Sample HTML button:

```
<a href="#" onclick="editPlist('STRING1', 'STRING2', 'BOOL')" class="buttong">1 : Round 1</a>
```

The button click runs this script: (the PHP in the url line generates the address of the file I want to run.)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function editPlist(stage, dance, oldValue)
{
    alert('test ' + stage + dance + oldValue);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: <?php echo '"'.dirname(curPageURL()).'/PlistEditorFunction.php"' ?>,
        data: {"var1" : stage , "var2" : dance , "var3" : oldValue},
        success: function(msg){
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); //Anything you want
        }
    });
}
```

In the external php file PlistEditorFunction.php, I try to log a fake error and load the variables, but the error never shows. this is the beginning of the php file:

```
$msg = 'test error message';
error_log('['.date("F j, Y, g:i a e O").']'.$msg."<br /> \n", 3,  $phperrorPath);
if (isset($_POST['data']) and trim($_POST['data']) != '' ) {
    $stage = trim($_POST['var1']);
    $dance = trim($_POST['var2'])
    $oldValue = trim($_POST['var3']);
}
```

I know that the php script will only be run if the domain name matches file where the ajax is being run from. The two files are next to each other so I know that this isn't the problem.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you watching your ajax requests with Chrome developer tools or Firebug? You can verify that your ajax requests are being sent correctly and view the full response that way. Using chrome, open the developer tools and go to the network pane. Then click the button on yor web page and watch for new entries in the metwork pane.

Comment: Thanks, The script now works and updates properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After mwotton's comment, I figured out that ajax was undefined. jQuery was imported, so that wan't the problem. I found the answer was I had to change $.ajax to jquery.ajax.

Some hosts don't use "$" to denote jQuery. My web host uses "jquery" instead.

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
url: <?php echo '"'.dirname(curPageURL()).'/PlistEditorFunction.php"' ?>
```

to

```
url: 'PlistEditorFunction.php'
```

and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Several things look strange.

Please verify that the url you call is in fact what you think it is. In order to do that, use a console / inspector. I recommend firebug. When you make the ajax call, it will display the url of the page you're requesting with ajax.

If it is correct, then your url param is not the problem. Next I would look at the php file itself. Try throwing an echo statement in the php file so that way your ajax response can verify that its being run. whatever you echo in the file `PlistEditorFunction.php` will be the response param in the success function

```
success: function( response ) {
    console.log(response); //should be the echo'd statement of PlistEditorFunction.php
}
```